# Adding a new column into a SharePoint list using VBA code

Tags: vba, sharepoint-online

I currently have an Excel workbook with a VBA project that has grid tables that get checked against the rows and columns.)

The code as it stands works fine, but currently the data is stored in the excel book, meaning there can only be one copy, which can not be edited by multiple people, and I have been challenged to move the background data to SharePoint, just using the excel data as a front end.

I need to be able to add/remove new columns and rows.

In terms of the rows, this would translate to adding a new entry to the list, which I can do with the following functions that I adapted from found code:

```
Public Function AddItemToSharePointList(ByVal sharepointListName As String, ByVal inputValueForField As String, ByVal FieldNameVar As String, _
                                            Optional methodID As Long = 1, Optional ByVal SharepointUrl As String = KSP_DEFAULT_SHAREPOINT) As Boolean

    Dim objXMLHTTP As Object
    
    Dim strListNameOrGuid As String
    Dim strBatchXml As String
    Dim strSoapBody As String
    
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    
    strListNameOrGuid = sharepointListName
    
    
    'Add New Item'
    strBatchXml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>" & _
                        "<Method ID='" & methodID & "' Cmd='New'>" & _
                            "<Field Name='ID'>New</Field><Field Name='" & _
                            FieldNameVar & "'>" & inputValueForField & "</Field>" & _
                        "</Method>" & _
                    "</Batch>"
    
    
    objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", SharepointUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
    objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"
    
    strSoapBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " _
     & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " _
     & "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><UpdateListItems " _
     & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>" & strListNameOrGuid _
     & "</listName><updates>" & strBatchXml & "</updates></UpdateListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    
    objXMLHTTP.send strSoapBody
    
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        AddItemToSharePointList = True
    Else
        AddItemToSharePointList = False
    End If
    
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

Plus similar functions to delete or amend fields

This works fine (I have a class that manages a SharePoint list and table it is imported too), but ideally I need to be able to add/remove columns to the SharePoint list using VBA.  I have seen people suggest they have done this with other languages, but I do not know enough about XML to adapt this.

Does anyone know if I can add a new column to a SharePoint list, and ideally remove it too.
I would also need to make sure it is included in the view I am importing.

I have tried adapting the above functions with this found code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Fields ListUrl="Lists/Test">
 <Add>
  <Field ID="{1174073D-CD08-4A8A-A70E-5199200E04AC}" 
         Name="TestField"  
         Required="TRUE" 
         Indexed="TRUE" 
         MaxLength="255" 
         Type="Text" 
         DisplayName="TestField" />
 </Add>
</Fields>
```

But I don't really know enough about XML or the schemas requests.

Comment: If anyone knows a solution to this, I am still looking for an answer.  The only other approach I can think of is have multiple values in a long text field, separated by a particular char or string, but then that will make the rest of the VBA code messier.