# Excel VBA insert data into sharepoint list (Column Option multiple values) - does not insert

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a problem inserting data into a SharePoint list, using a VBA macro. The macro is inserting values ​​into several columns of a SharePoint list.

The only problem is that this list has an Option column where the user can select multiple values.

The line that moves the value to the column is as follows:
...
rs.addNew
...
rs.Fields("ProductType") = varProductType  'this variable will always have only one value.rs.update

Comments:

- varTipoProduto is a string.
- The content of the varProductType variable is a valid value for the "ProductType" column
- When saving column values in SharePoint, the "Product Type" column is empty.
- All others are being recorded correctly.
- In addition, there are other columns of the Option type, which are being recorded. But these columns are single selection.

Would anyone have a tip?

Ricardo Albano

I've already tried writing the data to an array, with ";#" and ";"

Comment: A similar question has been asked here recently.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536400/adding-a-new-column-into-a-sharepoint-list-using-vba-code

Comment: Ask at [Sharepoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Welcome Ricardo! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!